# related name in parent model in django if inherited in other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I created a model which can be inherited in other models

**Parent Model**

```py
class Edit_Lane_Info(models.Model):
    lane_info = models.OneToOneField(Edit_Lane, related_name='$(class)s', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.lane_info:
            self.lane_info.delete()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

```py
class Status (Edit_Lane_Info, models.Model):  # parent class inherited
    ......
```

```py
class Anpr(Edit_Lane_Info, models.Model): # parent class inherited
    ....
```

```py
class Sensor_Details(Edit_Lane_Info, models.Model): # parent class inherited
    .............
```

Now my question is how can I pass related_name in Edit_Lane_Info(parent model) uniquely. I used `related_name='$(class)s`, but not working

**Edit_Lane model**

```py
class Edit_Lane(models.Model):
    Anpr_Ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default="NA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `related_name` contains `$` instead of `%`

To work around this problem, when you are using related_name, part of the name should contain the `%(app_label)s` or `%(class)s`

**EDIT:**

For the the inheritance, you don't need to inherit from `models.Model` in each following **class**:`Status`, `Anpr`, `Sensor_Details`  since `Edit_Lane_Info` is already inherited from `models.Model`

You should have it that way

```
Edit_Lane_Info(models.Model)

class Status (Edit_Lane_Info):
class Anpr (Edit_Lane_Info):
class Sensor_Details (Edit_Lane_Info):
```

Comment: almost working, now I am getting the following error `File "/home/jana/Documents/working/tada_new/tada_new/tada_backend/Project/Tollplaza/Tollapp/models.py", line 108
    Edit_Lane, related_name='%(class)s',
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
`

Comment: if you still have the error, let me see your model `Edit_lane`

Comment: Still I got the same problem

Comment: can you show me what this becomes `lane_info = models.OneToOneField(Edit_Lane, related_name='$(class)s', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
`